# Installing Ubuntu on SSD drive

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days.

I want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows.

I have windows on a SSD that I left 30gb unallocated space for Ubuntu ,also have 3 1tb

HDD set up as a raid 5, this is all fresh installed on a new machine.

My problem is Ubuntu wants to install on one of the hdd in the raid and not the partition on the SSD. I even unplugged all the raid 5 HHDs and then the installer doesn't see Windows.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

I do know that the SSD is set to IDE in the BIOS, that was the only way I could get windows on it with the DVD ROM I have. and Ubuntu doesn't see the raid it just shows individual hdd.

specs:

- windows 64bit
- gigabyte ga-990fxa-ud3
- amd fx-3250
- legacy raid

Comment: Is it Windows 8 or higher? Does the computer have UEFI instead of BIOS? Please edit the question with new information.

Comment: Just for clarity - is the 30gb of unallocated space IN the windows partition?

Comment: Using LiveCD, do you see the partition if you install and run GParted?

Comment: yes when i run the live and go to gparted i see the 120gb ssd with the 90gb windows partition, and then there is 30gb unalocated

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Ubuntu 18.04 and above**

New installations of recent versions of Ubuntu does not use a separate swap partition any more. They use a swap file by default. You only need a separate swap partition if you want to enable hibernation at a later stage.

**Original Answer**

Choose “Something Else” during installation.

[image]

A new screen will pop out letting you choose where to install Ubuntu, format, make partitions, etc. Follow carefully the bellow:

Choose the SSD (I refer to it as `/dev/sda` here. Yours may be different.) and create two partitions in the unallocated space as follows:

- Use most of the 30GB for the `/` partition. Leave 2 to 4GB at the end
  for the `swap` partition. The `/` partition should be of the type
  ext4 and have mount-point of `/` as below:

[image]

- The swap partition should be of the type **"Swap Area"** with no
  mount-pont.

The device for boot loader installation should be the default the `/dev/sda`.

Hope this helps